# How to copy files from a directory to its parent directory by using copy command of grunt

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am developing an application in angular js and GRUNT build tool.
I want to copy all the files of demo directory to its parent directory.
For example the folder structure is like below

```
root
|
parent1
  |
   Demo
     |
      file1
      file2
```

Like paret1, root directory many contain other directory which may contain demo folder.
Want the files inside demo to be copied to its corresponding parent directory.

I m using the following:

```
copy:{
  taskCopy: {
    src: 'root/**/demo/*',
    dest:'root/**/demo/..'

  }
}
```

Getting error while executing this task

Comment: And the error is...?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build the file object dynamically

```
copy:{
      taskCopy: {
        files: [
        {   
            expand: true, 
            cwd: 'root', 
            src: '**/demo/*.*',
            dest: 'root/',
            rename: function(dest, src) {
                  return dest + src.replace(/demo|Demo\//g, "");
                }
        }]

      }
    }
```

In the above code I am assuming that all the inner folder (folder inside parent1) name is either `demo` or `Demo`